# Wait.On() on Apache Beam Python SDK version

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using Apache Beam on Python and would like to ask what is the equivalent of Apache Beam Java `Wait.on()` on python SDK?

currently I am having problem with this code snippet below

```
    if len(output_pcoll) > 1:
        merged = (tuple(output_pcoll) |
                  'MergePCollections1' >> beam.Flatten())
    else:
        merged = output_pcoll[0]

    outlier_side_input = self.construct_outlier_side_input(merged)

    (merged |
     "RemoveOutlier" >>
     beam.ParDo(utils.Remove_Outliers(),
                beam.pvalue.AsDict(outlier_side_input)) |
     "WriteToCSV" >>
     beam.io.WriteToText('../../ML-DATA/{0}.{1}'.format(self.BUCKET,
                         self.OUTPUT), num_shards=1))
```

it seems Apache Beam does not wait until the code on `self.construct_outlier_side_input` finished executing and result in empty side input when executing "RemoveOutlier" in the next pipeline. In Java version you can use `Wait.On()` to wait for `construct_outlier_side_input` to finish executing, however I could not find the equivalent method in the Python SDK.

--Edit--
what i am trying to achieve is almost the same as in this link,
https://rmannibucau.metawerx.net/post/apache-beam-initialization-destruction-task

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I'm new to python too, what I want you to make sure of is that the issue is mainly about timing and not anything else.. What I understand is that for you to have multithreading in python you have to implement that, otherwise the code would execute synchronously; statement after the other. You should first test that if you wait x seconds before removing outlier that your code behaves as you expect it, you can use time.sleep(x), you may check this link as well: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-make-python-wait

Comment: Can you explain your usecase ? Are you trying to remove outliers from the merged dataset?

Comment: HasnaaIbraheem thanks, i tried that before posting it here, but still no success.

@jjayadeep, yes, i am trying to remove outliers from the merged dataset, but the outliers i am trying to remove is local outliers. So from the merged dataset i construct a dictionary consists of item name as key and a list of its value as the dictionary value, then i use that dictionary as side input when removing outliers

Comment: I assume this is in a streaming pipeline? If yes what is the window you are applying to the SideInput data?

Comment: @RezaRokni no it's not, this is batch pipeline

Comment: SideInput in batch mode will wait for all data for the stage to be completed before it is used in the next transform.

Comment: @RezaRokni, can you give me link to the documentation that says something about it?

Comment: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs
There is some references in that doc, although its not as clear as it should be. In the Batch non-windowed case, everything is in the Global Window. So the PCollectionView should be fully materialised before its used in the PCollection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use additional outputs feature of Beam to do this.

A sample code snippet is as follows

```
results = (words | beam.ParDo(ProcessWords(), cutoff_length=2, marker='x')
           .with_outputs('above_cutoff_lengths', 'marked strings',
                         main='below_cutoff_strings'))
below = results.below_cutoff_strings
above = results.above_cutoff_lengths
marked = results['marked strings']  # indexing works as well
```

Once you run the above code snippet you get multiple PCollections such as below, above and marked. You can then use side inputs to further filter or join the results

Hope that helps.

## Update

Based on the comments I would like to mention that Apache Beam has capabilities to do stateful processing with the help of `ValueState` and `BagState`. If the requirement is to read through a PCollection and then make decisions based on if a prior value is present or not then such requirements can be handled through `BagState` as shown below:-

```
def process(self,
              element,
              timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam,
              window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam,
              buffer_1=beam.DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER_STATE_1),
              buffer_2=beam.DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER_STATE_2),
              watermark_timer=beam.DoFn.TimerParam(WATERMARK_TIMER)):

    # Do you processing here
    key, value = element
    # Read all the data from buffer1
    all_values_in_buffer_1 = [x for x in buffer_1.read()]

    if StatefulDoFn._is_clear_buffer_1_required(all_values_in_buffer_1):
        # clear the buffer data if required conditions are met.
        buffer_1.clear()

    # add the value to buffer 2
    buffer_2.add(value)

    if StatefulDoFn._all_condition_met():
      # Clear the timer if certain condition met and you don't want to trigger
      # the callback method.
      watermark_timer.clear()

    yield element

  @on_timer(WATERMARK_TIMER)
  def on_expiry_1(self,
                  timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam,
                  window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam,
                  key=beam.DoFn.KeyParam,
                  buffer_1=beam.DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER_STATE_1),
                  buffer_2=beam.DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER_STATE_2)):
    # Window and key parameters are really useful especially for debugging issues.
    yield 'expired1'
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solustion doesn't work for me, since what is passed to my `Remove_Outliers()` will be every element in the pcollection, and to construct a dictionary like this { item: [price1, price2,...,priceN] } i will need to have same state saved e.g. whether a particular item exists in the dict or not, if exists append the list. And saving state in apache beam is not supported.

Comment: @ruka - Beam provides Stateful processing semantics. I have updated my answer with the details that you can refer to. If it helped please do accept the answer.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention my pipeline is batch pipeline. Thank you for the detailed explanation tho

Comment: You can use the `BagState` and `ValueState` for the batch pipeline as well. You can find more details here - https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html. If this answer was helpful please do accept my answer.